# Process Recodring before meeting is over in bigbluebutton

Tags: bigbluebutton

I have to process recording after every 10 minutes while the meeting is going on, so that I can get the recordings file immediately, I tried to change the `bbb-record-core.timer` value as shown in documentation but it is process after the meeting is ended.

I want to start processing as soon as recording starts or every ten minutes without ending the meeting, the recording will be going on and in background the process should start.

Is there anything that I can do, to achieve this.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?? we also want a similar workflow to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the bbb-record-core.timer file. Be default, this file is configured to run it every 30 seconds. You can use a new attribute called OnCalendar and use cron to set it up based on your requirements.

Here's a resource that helped me out.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bigbluebutton-dev/E4XJ6yB22eQ